# image is not retrieved from database into html edit form

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Using java, spring boot and html., I have created a small website where I have displayed image in front page with the help of html and multipart file

in controller and I have given private String image; in entity.class and I have created image column in mysql database as varchar() type.

image path is saved into database and image is displayed in html front page but the problem is when i try to edit the image, the edit_form is displayed but in image field the image path is not showing from database. other text fields are retrieved from database but image field path is not retrieved.

I also tried th:field=${} to retrieve the image from database but is shows Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputFileFieldTagProcessor.

There are similar questions like this one on Stack Overflow. But I could not find right answers for my problem. and I have tried many ways to solve this problem but nothing works for me.

so, can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem.

```
1.edit_form.html

<main class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="starter-template mt-5 col-lg-12" align="center">
<form th:action="@{/home}" th:object = "${gameofthrones}" method="POST"    enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    
                        <div class = "form-group" >
                       
                            <label> Image </label> 
                            <input
                            type = "file"
                            name = "fileImage"
                            class = "form-control"
                            id = "fileImage"
                            accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
                            /> 
                           <br/>
                    
                           
<a class="nav-link" th:href="got-images+'/'+${id} + '/' + ${image}">LINK TEST</a>
                        </div>

2.Controller.Class

    @GetMapping("/got/edit/{id}")
    public String editGotForm(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) 
    {
        Gameofthrones gameofthrones = new Gameofthrones();
        gameofthrones = gotService.getById(34);
        model.addAttribute("gameofthrones", gameofthrones);     
        return "edit_got";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/home",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public String saveGot(Model model,@ModelAttribute("gameofthrones")  Gameofthrones gameofthrones, @RequestParam("fileImage") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException 
    
    {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        gameofthrones.setImage(fileName);
        Gameofthrones saveGot = gotService.savGot(gameofthrones);
        
        String uploadDir = "./got-images/" + saveGot.getId();
        Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadDir);
        
        if(!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
            Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
        }
        
        try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
            Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(fileName);
            System.out.println(filePath.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
            Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("Could not save uploaded file: " + fileName);
        }
        
        System.out.println("In save Test" + gameofthrones.getHeading()+"::");
        System.out.println("In save Test" + gameofthrones.getParagraph()+"::");
        System.out.println("In save Test" + gameofthrones.getImage()+"::");
        
        gotService.savGot(gameofthrones);
        
        List<Gameofthrones> alldata = gotService.getAllGots();
        model.addAttribute("GameofthronesData", alldata);
        
        return "home";
    }
```

3.image

[image: edit_formimage]

Comment: Browsers won't let you prefill a file upload field -- that's just not possible.  As for the other error, we can't debug that without the entire stack trace. (There's not enough information there.)

Comment: @Metroids I didn't get any error, in the process of getting file path I have modified code then only I get error. I've added th:field=*{} in html input tag for getting file path then i get thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException.